# Mysql select all that match a number in string

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wildcard

Assume my table column contains the following 2 string rows:

```
       1, 5, 2, 31, 12, 1212, 111
       21, 25, 32, 43, 112, 212, 311
```

I need a query to select a row that contains number `1` and contains number `2`

My Query is:

```
      SELECT *
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE My_String LIKE '%1%' AND My_String LIKE '%2%'
```

now this returns both of the rows when i want it to return only the first row.

It selects second row because numbers `21, 25, 32, 112, 212, 311` also contain number `1` and `2`.

My question is how do i select all those rows where numbers `1` and `2` are contained in a string but not in 2-3 digit numbers. I want it to match strictly to those `1` and `2`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any sure way of achieving that. You may need to change the way (data structure) you store data in that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b082d/5

```
select * from testtable
where instr(concat(', ', longstring, ', '), ', 2,') >0;

select * from testtable
where instr(concat(', ', longstring, ', '), ', 1,') >0 
and  instr(concat(', ', longstring, ', '), ', 2,') >0;
```

Comment: +1 I love the idea. it saves many comparisons compared to what i wrote in my answer. i just want to note that since the requirement is to have both numbers 1 and 2 appear, you might add an and condition with similar behavior for number 1 :)

Comment: seems to be working, will this work also if i have to search for 2 digit number? for example i want to find all record that match against number 1 and 15. Can you also explain please how it retrieves the data? using concat and instr dont know what instr does

Comment: off course it will work. You can try on sqlfiddle link I provided for other examples.

Comment: can you explain if you have time what kind of magic query does that it works ?

Comment: It is really not hard, with concat method it just adds ", " to all rows beginning and also end.
than your string becomes ", 1, 5, 2, 31, 12, 1212, 111, ".
So you can always enable to search like ",1 ".
Iw we didn't add ", " to beginning and end of string you couldn't search first and last item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression. [[:<:]] is a beginning word boundary and [[:>:]] is end word boundary.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE My_String RLIKE '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'
AND   My_String RLIKE '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: so this will match strictly against numbers 1 and 2? so i would have: WHERE My_String RLIKE '[[:<:]][1],' AND My_String RLIKE '[[:<:]][2],' And [[:<:]][1], means begins with 1 and then there is comma right after?

Comment: Looks to me like that may be doing an OR rather than and AND ?

Comment: this is not good enough. it will fail if "1" or "2" is the last number and thus has no coma after it. same if the list contains only 1 or only 2. your solution must go over all possibilities of appearance: 1-beginning, 2- middle, 3-end 4-being the only element.

Comment: The comma counts as a word boundary also, so '[[:<:]][12][[:>:]]' will be comma agnostic. I didn't realize both had to be true, I thought it was either/or. TBH, comma separated lists of strings in tables is a sign that such information should be stored in a separate table with each value in the string saved as a row and associated with a particular record index. Then the select becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options:

1- As mentioned in a comment on the main post, change the structure and don't store concatenated strings

2- write a function that splits the string and checks if the numbers 1 and 2 appear in the tokens after splitting.

3- write "where" clause that captures every possibility of appearance for a string:
   a string can appear in the beginning, middle, end of the list or be the only element in the list. the last one, is not important since you require 1 and 2 to appear in a row, and therefore a list String containing a single element should be eliminated. so:

```
select *
from MyTable
where (My_String like '1,%'  or My_String like '%, 1,%' or My_String like '%, 1') 
and (My_String like '2,%'  or My_String like '%, 2,%' or My_String like '%, 2')
```